# ASP.NET MVC multi-instance session management on amazon ec2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, session, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, multiple-instances

I have a web application written in asp.net mvc2. Currently hosted on amazon cloud ec2. Because of growing traffic we want move multi instance enviorenment. I have a custom session class which currently initiate at session start (global asax) and i am using via getter or setter class in application. Because of multi instance chore i have to handle hole security architecture. I am looking a better way to handle this problem.

```
    protected void OnSessionStart()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("mySessionObject", new MyAppSession());
    }


    public static MyAppSession GetMySessionObject(HttpContextBase current)
    {
        if (current != null)
        {
            if (current.Session != null)
                if (current.Session["mySessionObject"] == null)
                {
                    current.Session.Add("mySessionObject", new MyAppSession());
                }
        }
        if ( current != null && current.Session != null)
            return (MyAppSession ) (current.Session["mySessionObject"]);
        return null;
    }


and so on.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is wide options for session management on multiinstance enviorenment.

> **Session State Database**
>   If we want to affinity per request then we have
>   to keep session information in database and pass information between
>   them. This is hard to implement.
>
> **Stick User Session**
>   With this you don't have to implement custom
>   session management. You can stick a user and make affinity per
>   instance instead of per request.

I choose second one.